# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Invalid Memory Alloc Request size due to Field size Limit - 1GB in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, psql

For one of the table have three columns
id- int
name - varchar,
data - bytea data type

For the data column the content for some of the rows is more than 700MB.

The data is successfully inserted. But, when I'm trying to fetch that particular row which is having huge volume of data (around 700MB or more than that) I'm getting the error "**Invalid memory alloc request size 1236252631**"

The rows which is with less data/content I can able to fetch the file successfully. But for these specific rows I'm getting an error.

I have checked bytea_outout which is in hex format. I changed the parameters such as work_mem and shared_buffers but didn't resolved the issue.

Later, I got to know that while fetching the bytea file/content from the postgreSQL, it will change it to text format and why may allocate 2x of the binary and it may cross beyond 1GB and it is failing.

So, there is some limit for the **field size for the postgreSQL which is 1GB.**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html

The same error I'm getting when I'm trying to fetch the particular row oof the table in Java, Pgadmin or dbeaver etc..

The query I'm trying to use is usual select query i;e

```
select data from table_name where name ='name'
```

When I try to fetch other columns such as I'd or name etc I can fetch but when I try to fetch the data column then facing the issue that too specific to the huge volume of data.

The table has more than 70k rows. Now it is very difficult to change the table structure if any required as already data is already inserted successfully.

The issue is with only that bytea datatype column which is storing huge volume of data.

Hence, how could I resolve this issue ? Any solution to enhance this limit or any other solution? Could anyone please share the insights would help me a lot.

Comment: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException" looks like a Java error message or something similar. What client are you using? I suppose it is a limitation of the client, not the database. What happens if you use the native client [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)?

Comment: Same error. Any client even from postgreSQL client such as Pgadmin or Dbeaver etc I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly pointed out the issue.

What you can do is, read data in smaller chunks. This will avoid memory issues when dealing with large data.

Something like this (JAVA):

```
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "name_value");
    preparedStatement.setFetchSize(100); // Set data fetch size here

    try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            byte[] dataBytes = resultSet.getBytes("data");
            //process or concatenate data here
        }
    }
}catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This might increase execution time, but will work in your case.

Comment: Thank you. But small query, I need the original file to send it back to application. So, if I follow this procedure? Do I get the original content which is stored in db? I can see that fetch size is 100. So, will it fetch entire size by splitting into 100 for single batch? Could you please provide concat logic too if possible as I need original content (byte[] at last). So that I can pass this final byte[] to the UI.

Comment: For the specific rows I'm getting the error. I think your answer will work if we have more no of rows and proceed chunk by chunk. But in my case if we call select query for the particular row then unable to fetch the result. Please correct me if i understood wrongly.

Comment: I am expecting that you are reading in Byte Array and you can concatenate them like (https://www.baeldung.com/java-concatenate-arrays).

Comment: What you mean "Will work if we have more number of rows"

Comment: I mean to say for example we have 10 rows then we can split the query in a batch of 1 or 2 so that we can fetch the data in batches. But here the case is we are unable to fetch some rows. For example select * from table where name ='xyz_with_huge_volume_data'. so here if we execute this query. We will get the error. So, my query is, the mentioned code will split the no of rows into batches (fetch size) I think but even after split if it calls that particular row we may get the same error since that single row itself the data is very huge. Please correct me if I understand wrongly. Thanks